# Swift, UIKit. Looking for Coordinator pattern tutorial, NO storyboard

Tags: swift, design-patterns, mvvm, uikit

I have searched practically everywhere for some tutorials on Coordinator Pattern with no storyboard.

Maybe someone can share his code from Github so I can have look?

Is anyone able to recommend something? Tutorial, a book to buy, anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps) by Paul Hudson. But it's written by using **storyboard**.

If you want to use uikit without storyboard, delete `Main.storyboard` first.

Inside `Info.plist` file, delete the rows with the following keys.

- Application Scene Manifest/Scene Configuration/Application Session Role/Storyboard Name
- Main storyboard file base name

In `SceneDelegate` class of `SceneDelegate.swift`, add this property.

```swift
var coordinator: Coordinator?
```

Replace the following code in `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` of `SceneDelegate.swift`

```swift
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
let navigationController =  UINavigationController()
coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationController)
coordinator?.start()
window.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I hope you may keep on learning coordinator pattern.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. I've been following that tutorial but I fail to understand few things. I have actually managed work without storyboard on this one. The problem with the tutorial is that it shows some usage of Coordinator patter but it does not show specifically how to combine these elements. Perhaps how many "screens" for one coordinator, or how to pass some data when you cannot modify start() method to take parameters. I found some walkaround and it works but I have no idea if this a correct established way of doing so. Kind regards.

Comment: I guess you probably understand the basic usages of coordinator pattern. If you feel things you do will be wrong and messy, you should use [XCoordinator](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/XCoordinator) package. It is a handy package that supports navigation on coordinator pattern. You don't need to start from scratch. You can see the [example](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/XCoordinator-Example) of how to use it. Give it a trial.